# Counting prefixes in a joined table in SQL

Tags: sql, count, prefix

I am trying to count how many makes of car a person owns. Car makes are only defined by a prefix in my Links table.

```
Table 1 (Person)
UniqueID         Name
PER0001          Adrian
PER0002          Michael
Per0003          James

Table 2 (Links)
UniqueID         LinkEnd1_ID         LinkEnd2_ID
LIN0001          PER0001             FER02332
LIN0002          PER0001             FER02112
LIN0003          PER0001             POR12122
LIN0004          PER0002             FER12321
LIN0005          PER0003             MAS12382
LIN0006          PER0003             FER22982
LIN0006          PER0003             MAS12232

Output (option 1)
Name             Car_Make           Count
Adrian           FER                2
Adrian           POR                1
Michael          FER                1
James            MAS                2
James            FER                1

Output (option 2 - preferred)
Name             FER           POR            MAS
Adrian           1             2
Michael          1
James            1                            2
```

The reason I am using a link table to count the number of car makes is because every car make has a different table I would need to join in.

I've tried

`select count left(LinkEnd2_ID,3)` which doesnt work, i've also tried group by which I cant seem to crack.

I guess what I want to be able to do is

```
select 
  count(left(LinkEnd2_ID,3)='FER'
  ,count(left(LinkEnd2_ID,3)='POR'
  ,count(left(LinkEnd2_ID,3)='MAS'
```

but thats a query in a select and I decipher how to code that properly.

Heres where I am starting from (or the base I keep going back to start afresh)-

```
SELECT 
  Person.Unique_ID
  ,Person.Name
  ,left(Link.LinkEnd2_ID,3) as Car_Make
FROM
  Person
LEFT JOIN
  Links as Link
  on Person.Unique_ID = Link.LinkEnd1_ID
```

Any help you can offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly there, you just need to add a group by, and change all the columns to aggregate functions.

Your option 1:

```
SELECT 
  max(Person.Name) as Person_Name
  ,left(Link.LinkEnd2_ID,3) as Car_Make
  ,count(*) as No_of_Car
FROM
  Person
LEFT JOIN
  Links as Link
  on Person.Unique_ID = Link.LinkEnd1_ID
GROUP BY
   Person.Unique_ID
```

For your option 2, you need to wrap your aggregate functions around case statements

you have to hardcode the 3 different car make, so if you have unknown number of them, it wouldn't work.

```
SELECT 
  max(Person.Name) as Person_Name
  ,sum(case when left(Link.LinkEnd2_ID,3) ='FER' then 1 else 0 end) as FER
  ,sum(case when left(Link.LinkEnd2_ID,3) ='POR' then 1 else 0 end) as POR
  ,sum(case when left(Link.LinkEnd2_ID,3) ='MAS' then 1 else 0 end) as MAS
FROM
  Person
LEFT JOIN
  Links as Link
  on Person.Unique_ID = Link.LinkEnd1_ID
GROUP BY
   Person.Unique_ID
```

Comment: Fantastic, I went with option 2. Thank you so much! Sorry to squeeze on another question here, but how to I add them up in a final column at the end? (I will be ignoring certain makes of car so it isnt the total number of links, it would be FER + POR + MAS for example).

Comment: ,sum(case when left(Link.LinkEnd2_ID,3) in list ('FER','POR',MAS' then 1 else 0 end) as Total ??

Comment: The logic is 
  ,sum(case when left(Link.LinkEnd2_ID,3) in ('FER','POR',MAS') then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL